# Is it one channel ops affect another channel ops

Tags: go, channel

I made this simple code, trying to know how's channel works, somehow if channel c is sent after channel b is sent, channel in last routine is not being sent,

I have 2 channel, channel c is for spliting channel b to 4 part of slice.

```
 package main

 import (
      "fmt"
      "strconv"
 )

 func runner(idx int, c chan []int, b chan []int) {
      var temp []int
      fmt.Println("runner " + strconv.Itoa(idx))
      bucket := <-b
      for k, v := range bucket {
           if v != 0 {
                temp = append(temp, v)
                bucket[k] = 0
           }
           if len(temp) == 5 {
                break
           }
      }

      //Strange condition if channel c is sent after channel b is sent,
      //somehow the last chan is not being sent
      b <- bucket
      c <- temp

      //this is right if channel b is sent after channel c is sent
    //c <- temp
    //b <- bucket

 }

 func printer(c chan []int) {
      for {
           select {
           case msg := <-c:
                fmt.Println(msg)
                //time.Sleep(time.Second * 1)
           }
      }
 }

 func main() {

      c := make(chan []int, 5)
      bucket := make(chan []int)

      go runner(1, c, bucket)
      go runner(2, c, bucket)
      go runner(3, c, bucket)
      go runner(4, c, bucket)

      bucket <- []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20}

      go printer(c)

      var input string
      fmt.Scanln(&input)

 }
```

Comment: It's not obvious what actually is not clear for you with this code. What do you expect to get and what you actually get?

Comment: Have u run the code? please check the runner function,  if u sent to channel c first and then b, u will have the right condition, this is what I don't understand, I hope someone would explain this channel behaviour

Comment: "u will have the right condition" --- that's the problem with the question: you have not explained what the "right" is, and what the "wrong" is. PS: please try to avoid using "c", "u", "b" and other shortenings.

Comment: thx @zerkms , kennytm just point it out right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  bucket := make(chan []int)
```

Your `b` channel's capacity is 0. This means whenever you send something to this channel, the channel is full immediately and will block until a receiver reads the channel.

When there is only one runner left, no one is going to call `bucket := <-b` to read the last bucket, thus this last goroutine is stuck forever on the `b <- bucket` line, and thus the next line `c <- temp` will never be called for this last goroutine.

Comment: Ahhh I see now, no other routine read the channel `<-b`, so then it will stuck forever on `b <- bucket`, so then I made change on printer func for reading the b channel 
`func printer(c chan []int, b chan []int) {
     for {
          select {
          case msg := <-c:
               fmt.Println(msg)
               //time.Sleep(time.Second * 1)
          case msg := <-b:
               fmt.Println(msg)
          }
     }
}`

Comment: Thank you very very very much

Comment: the problem is no one read the last b channel so it will stuck or block